# Cerrar div al abrir otro con Js

Tags: javascript

Actualmente, estoy en uno de mis primeros proyectos de desarrollo. He llegado a un punto en el que no sé como hacer una función con JS que abra un div y cierre el que está abierto. Necesitaría una función que, según su clase, no requiera hacer clic en el div para cerrarlo y lo haría al hacer clic para abrir otro.

```
function abreFichaRte(idloca) {
  let divgoster = document.getElementById(idloca);
  divgoster.classList.toggle('mostrar_rte');
  divgoster.classList.toggle('esconder_rte');
}
```

HTML

Aquí dejo un par de ejemplos del esquema donde está el div que se quiere tratar.

```
<div class="plt_entr">
    <div class="nom_plt" onclick="abreFichaRte('cont_img_entr1')" title="abrir">
        Patatas Bravas &#8675
    </div>
    <div class="linea_plt_pvp"></div>
    <div class="pvp_plt">
        8.€
    </div>
    <div id="cont_img_entr1" class="esconder_rte cont_img_plt">
        <div class="txt_alerg_plt">
            Alérgenos: 
            <div class="div_alerg"></div>
            <div class="div_alerg"></div>
            <div class="div_alerg"></div>
            <div class="div_alerg"></div>
        </div>
        <img src="./multimedia/pexels-ruslan-khmelevsky-14118125.jpg" alt="" id="img_foto">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="plt_entr">
<div class="nom_plt" onclick="abreFichaRte('cont_img_entr2')" title="abrir">
    Tabla de Ibéricos &#8675
</div>
<div class="linea_plt_pvp"></div>
<div class="pvp_plt">
    15.€
</div>
<div id="cont_img_entr2" class="esconder_rte cont_img_plt">
    <div class="txt_alerg_plt">
        Alérgenos: 
        <div class="div_alerg"></div>
        <div class="div_alerg"></div>
        <div class="div_alerg"></div>
        <div class="div_alerg"></div>
    </div>
    <img src="./multimedia/pexels-ruslan-khmelevsky-14118125.jpg" alt="" id="img_foto">
</div>
```

Esta es la función que he hecho con el toggle, cambia la clase del div haciendo onclick, pero no sé como hacer para que antes identifique el que está abierto y lo cierre, para no tener todos los div abiertos o tener que hacer otra vez onclick para cambiar su estado.

Comment: lo que se hace por lo general es remove de todas seguido de un add del que te interesa así no tenes que andar buscando cual está abierta. lo manejas con una sola clase "mostrar"

Comment: Muestra un ejemplo de tu html con ambos div, porque tal como veo tu función me parece que estás duplicando **id** en los div y eso es lo que te causa el problema. Puedes modificar tu pregunta pulsando sobre el enlace [edit] que aparece en el pie de la misma.

Answer (score 1):

Con esto solucionas el problema del toggle también:

```js
function abreFichaRte(el) {
  let padre = el.parentNode
  let divhijo = padre.querySelector('.cont_img_plt');
  document.querySelectorAll('.cont_img_plt').forEach(function(x) {
    if (x != divhijo) {
      x.classList.remove('mostrar_rte')
      x.classList.add('esconder_rte')
    }
  })
  divhijo.classList.toggle('mostrar_rte')
  divhijo.classList.toggle('esconder_rte')
}
```

```css
.esconder_rte {
  display: none;
}

.mostrar_rte {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="plt_entr">
  <div class="nom_plt" onclick="abreFichaRte(this)" title="abrir">
    Patatas Bravas &#8675
  </div>
  <div class="linea_plt_pvp"></div>
  <div class="pvp_plt">
    8.€
  </div>
  <div class="esconder_rte cont_img_plt">
    <div class="txt_alerg_plt">
      Alérgenos:
      <div class="div_alerg"></div>
      <div class="div_alerg"></div>
      <div class="div_alerg"></div>
      <div class="div_alerg"></div>
    </div>
    <img src="./multimedia/pexels-ruslan-khmelevsky-14118125.jpg" alt="" id="img_foto">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="plt_entr">
  <div class="nom_plt" onclick="abreFichaRte(this)" title="abrir">
    Tabla de Ibéricos &#8675
  </div>
  <div class="linea_plt_pvp"></div>
  <div class="pvp_plt">
    15.€
  </div>
  <div class="esconder_rte cont_img_plt">
    <div class="txt_alerg_plt">
      Alérgenos:
      <div class="div_alerg"></div>
      <div class="div_alerg"></div>
      <div class="div_alerg"></div>
      <div class="div_alerg"></div>
    </div>
    <img src="./multimedia/pexels-ruslan-khmelevsky-14118125.jpg" alt="" id="img_foto">
  </div>
</div>
```

### Cambios realizados

1. Las llamadas a la función ahora son `abreFichaRte(this)`
2. Se han eliminado los **id** del div a esconder, no hacen falta con esta solución
3. La definición de la función ahora es así:

```
function abreFichaRte(el) {
```

donde **el** es el elemento clicado, representado por **this** en la llamada a la función

4. Dada la estructura del HTML se busca el padre de dicho elemento, para situarnos por encima de el para después buscar, a partir del padre, al div hijo que queremos esconder mediante `querySelector()`:

```
let padre = el.parentNode
let divhijo = padre.querySelector('.cont_img_plt');
```

5. Ahora nos recorremos todos los div con la clase común `.cont_img_plt` mediante `querySelectorAll()` y un `forEach()`, donde ponemos una función que nos evalue si el elemento **x** de cada ciclo se corresponde con el elemento **divhijo** descubierto anteriormente, y si no lo es entonces escondemos los elementos hallados con esa clase:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.cont_img_plt').forEach(function(x) {
  if (x != divhijo) {
    x.classList.remove('mostrar_rte')
    x.classList.add('esconder_rte')
  }
})
```

Y por último, conmutamos el estado de las clases **mostrar_rte** y **esconder_rte** del div hijo hallado.

```
divhijo.classList.toggle('mostrar_rte')
divhijo.classList.toggle('esconder_rte')
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se hace por lo general es removerle a todas los div las clases que "muestran", seguido de un add de la clase al div que te interesa así no tenes que andar buscando cual está abierta. lo manejas con una sola clase "mostrar/abrir/abierto".

El efecto "toggle" para que muestre/oculte y no quede uno siempre abierto lo lográs agregandole el "mostrar" sólo si antes no lo tenía.

algo así:

```js
ocultarTodos = () => {
  mostrados = document.querySelectorAll('.escondible.mostrar')
  if (mostrados) mostrados.forEach((m) => m.classList.remove('mostrar'))
}

mostrarMe = (ev) => {
  ocultarTodos()
  ev.currentTarget.parentNode.classList.add('mostrar')
}

togglearMe = (ev) => {
  yoSomos = ev.currentTarget.parentNode
  meVeo = yoSomos.classList.contains('mostrar')
  ocultarTodos()
  if (!meVeo) yoSomos.classList.add('mostrar')
}


clickeables = document.querySelectorAll('.escondible>h1')

clickeables.forEach((c) => c.addEventListener("click", togglearMe, false))
```

```css
.escondible {
  width: 30vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  border: dashed 1px red
}

.escondible h1 {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

.escondible p {
  display: none;
}

.escondible.mostrar p {
  display: block;
}

.escondible .toggler:before {
  content: "\25BC";
}

.escondible.mostrar .toggler:before {
  content: "\25B2";
}
```

```html
<div class="escondible">
  <h1>un div <span class="icon toggler"></span></h1>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut ornare viverra felis, vitae tempor purus sollicitudin et. Donec congue odio vel justo tincidunt cursus. Donec sollicitudin lacus a lectus luctus aliquam id in tellus. Integer ut elementum urna.
    Praesent libero nulla, sodales a risus a, imperdiet tempus nibh. Nunc et dui nunc. Nulla a lobortis leo. Sed ipsum nunc, ullamcorper vitae odio eget, ultrices molestie risus. Morbi eget velit ac erat euismod posuere. Donec eu libero ullamcorper, sollicitudin
    risus sed, posuere erat. Nunc laoreet feugiat lacus, et finibus risus aliquet a. Proin viverra id justo ut lacinia. Fusce aliquet, augue vel iaculis vulputate, mi nibh posuere turpis, quis mollis metus sapien ac turpis.
  </p>
</div>
<div class="escondible">
  <h1>un div <span class="icon toggler"></span></h1>
  <p>
    Etiam a diam ac velit dignissim varius et ac augue. Integer ut tortor vitae turpis ullamcorper maximus. Vestibulum bibendum lacus lectus, quis consectetur augue volutpat eget. Etiam consectetur interdum erat, quis commodo nisi fringilla quis. Cras eleifend
    bibendum libero. Ut tincidunt ex orci, ut malesuada tellus semper quis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Morbi malesuada lorem et odio tincidunt faucibus in eu orci. Orci varius natoque penatibus
    et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cras eget consectetur purus. Morbi mattis dapibus diam, a interdum magna.
  </p>
</div>
<div class="escondible">
  <h1>un div <span class="icon toggler"></span></h1>
  <p>
    Nunc sem sem, volutpat faucibus pellentesque vel, tempor et purus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse purus velit, fermentum ac volutpat id, eleifend non nisi. Donec id metus ligula. Quisque maximus scelerisque sapien non tincidunt. Duis quis dui a neque porta
    porttitor. Donec fermentum leo sed mauris vulputate viverra.
  </p>
</div>
<div class="escondible">
  <h1>un div <span class="icon toggler"></span></h1>
  <p>
    Aliquam in tortor faucibus, consectetur dolor ut, aliquet tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Ut quis velit ante. Morbi rutrum ultricies nibh in finibus. Nulla varius viverra ante a facilisis. Donec nisi turpis, laoreet
    at laoreet vel, imperdiet sit amet magna. Vivamus id dui risus. Suspendisse at metus tellus. Maecenas aliquet vel lacus nec lacinia.
  </p>
</div>
<div class="escondible">
  <h1>un div <span class="icon toggler"></span></h1>
  <p>
    Sed pellentesque dui eu orci eleifend, vel rutrum ex consequat. Maecenas tincidunt turpis a tortor lacinia convallis. Maecenas pharetra nisi tellus. Mauris porta libero ut urna finibus elementum. Sed est justo, tincidunt at interdum a, cursus ut erat.
    Nulla gravida, nulla ut rhoncus mollis, metus nisi viverra nibh, ac porta dolor felis eleifend orci. Etiam sollicitudin dolor ut sapien laoreet condimentum. Donec risus massa, congue sed hendrerit sed, lobortis nec mauris. Sed ultrices lorem sodales
    nulla aliquet bibendum. Nullam nec dapibus sem. In vel sem quis enim ultrices finibus eleifend sed metus. In elementum elit massa, et pellentesque felis porttitor a. Proin at augue id eros egestas posuere non id nulla. Praesent commodo sit amet est
    in facilisis. Sed vitae auctor velit. Nulla facilisi.
  </p>
</div>
```

bonus: sin javascript usando radiobuttons pero necesitas saber cuantos son y ponerles id a los labels

```css
.escondible {
  width: 30vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  border: dashed 1px red
}

.escondible h1 {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

.escondible p {
  display: none;
}

.escondible input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.escondible input[type="radio"]:checked~p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="escondible">
  <input type="radio" name="escondedor" id="div1" />
  <label for="div1">
  <h1>un div</h1>
  </label>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut ornare viverra felis, vitae tempor purus sollicitudin et. Donec congue odio vel justo tincidunt cursus. Donec sollicitudin lacus a lectus luctus aliquam id in tellus. Integer ut elementum urna.
    Praesent libero nulla, sodales a risus a, imperdiet tempus nibh. Nunc et dui nunc. Nulla a lobortis leo. Sed ipsum nunc, ullamcorper vitae odio eget, ultrices molestie risus. Morbi eget velit ac erat euismod posuere. Donec eu libero ullamcorper, sollicitudin
    risus sed, posuere erat. Nunc laoreet feugiat lacus, et finibus risus aliquet a. Proin viverra id justo ut lacinia. Fusce aliquet, augue vel iaculis vulputate, mi nibh posuere turpis, quis mollis metus sapien ac turpis.
  </p>
</div>
<div class="escondible">
  <input type="radio" name="escondedor" id="div2" />
  <label for="div2">
  <h1>un div</h1>
  </label>
  <p>
    Etiam a diam ac velit dignissim varius et ac augue. Integer ut tortor vitae turpis ullamcorper maximus. Vestibulum bibendum lacus lectus, quis consectetur augue volutpat eget. Etiam consectetur interdum erat, quis commodo nisi fringilla quis. Cras eleifend
    bibendum libero. Ut tincidunt ex orci, ut malesuada tellus semper quis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Morbi malesuada lorem et odio tincidunt faucibus in eu orci. Orci varius natoque penatibus
    et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cras eget consectetur purus. Morbi mattis dapibus diam, a interdum magna.
  </p>
</div>
<div class="escondible">
  <input type="radio" name="escondedor" id="div3" />
  <label for="div3">
  <h1>un div</h1>
  </label>
  <p>
    Nunc sem sem, volutpat faucibus pellentesque vel, tempor et purus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse purus velit, fermentum ac volutpat id, eleifend non nisi. Donec id metus ligula. Quisque maximus scelerisque sapien non tincidunt. Duis quis dui a neque porta
    porttitor. Donec fermentum leo sed mauris vulputate viverra.
  </p>
</div>
<div class="escondible">
  <input type="radio" name="escondedor" id="div4" />
  <label for="div4">
  <h1>un div</h1>
  </label>
  <p>
    Aliquam in tortor faucibus, consectetur dolor ut, aliquet tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Ut quis velit ante. Morbi rutrum ultricies nibh in finibus. Nulla varius viverra ante a facilisis. Donec nisi turpis, laoreet
    at laoreet vel, imperdiet sit amet magna. Vivamus id dui risus. Suspendisse at metus tellus. Maecenas aliquet vel lacus nec lacinia.
  </p>
</div>
<div class="escondible">
  <input type="radio" name="escondedor" id="div5" />
  <label for="div5">
  <h1>un div</h1>
  </label>
  <p>
    Sed pellentesque dui eu orci eleifend, vel rutrum ex consequat. Maecenas tincidunt turpis a tortor lacinia convallis. Maecenas pharetra nisi tellus. Mauris porta libero ut urna finibus elementum. Sed est justo, tincidunt at interdum a, cursus ut erat.
    Nulla gravida, nulla ut rhoncus mollis, metus nisi viverra nibh, ac porta dolor felis eleifend orci. Etiam sollicitudin dolor ut sapien laoreet condimentum. Donec risus massa, congue sed hendrerit sed, lobortis nec mauris. Sed ultrices lorem sodales
    nulla aliquet bibendum. Nullam nec dapibus sem. In vel sem quis enim ultrices finibus eleifend sed metus. In elementum elit massa, et pellentesque felis porttitor a. Proin at augue id eros egestas posuere non id nulla. Praesent commodo sit amet est
    in facilisis. Sed vitae auctor velit. Nulla facilisi.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Perdona, no estoy acostumbrado a esta plataforma, muchas gracias por tu alcaración, haciendo unos pequeños cambios he podido hacer que cierre el div abierto, pero he perdido el toggle para hacer click en el boton y se cierre el abierto. Siempre se queda un div abierto.

Comment: agregado el `togglearMe` que agrega el mostrar sólo si antes no lo tenía